# Where am I going wrong? Converging sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

I am struck with a dilemma concerning the following exercise in *Bartle*'s *Elements of Real Analysis*.

> Determine the convergence or the divergence of the sequence $(x_n)$
>   given by
>
> $$ x_n = \frac{1}{ n + 1} + \frac{1}{ n + 2}  + \cdots+ \frac{1}{ 2n}
>  \; ; \;\; n \in \Bbb N $$

Genius that I am, I actually proved the sequence was not Cauchy and hence is divergent only for the hints section to tell me that $(x_n)$ is increasing and is bounded above by $ \frac{n}{n + 1} \le  1 $ and hence converges by the Monotone Convergence Theorem, which is true. This is what I did:

I proved that $x_{n + 1} - x_n = \dfrac{ 1 }{ (2n + 2)( 2n + 1) }$ for an arbitrary natural number $n$. Then obtained a lower bound for $x_m - x_n$ for $m \gt n$ in the following manner,

\begin{align} 
x_m - x_n& = (x_m - x_{m - 1}) + (x_{m - 1} - x_{m - 2}) + \cdots ( x_{n + 1} - x_n )\\ 
& =  \dfrac{ 1 }{ (2(m - 1) + 2)( 2(m - 1) + 1)}  + \cdots + \dfrac{ 1 }{ (2n + 2)( 2n + 1)} \\ & \gt \dfrac{ m - n }{ 2m( 2m - 1)} \gt \dfrac{ m - n }{4m} \\ 
\end{align}

Specifically if $m = 2n$ then $ x_m - x_n \gt \frac{1}{8} $. And I thought this proves the sequence is not Cauchy. This is because there is $\epsilon = \frac{1}{8}  \gt 0 \;\; $ such that given any natural number $n$ there is $m (= 2n) \gt n $ such that $|x_{m} - x_n| = x_{m} - x_n \gt \frac{1}{8}$.

**Where am I going wrong??** Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your very last inequality $\frac{m-n}{2m(2m-1)}>\frac{m-n}{4m}$ is not correct. Maybe you got it by observing that $2m>2$ (which is true for $m\geq 2$) and then forgot to reverse the inequality when taking the inverse?

Actually, having proved that 
$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}$, you can deduce immediately that the series $\sum (x_{n+1}-x_n)$ is convergent, and hence that the sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent.

Of course, Sami's answer is much more interesting since it also gives the limit.

Comment: I actually got the inequality by $$ 2m - 1 \lt 2m \implies \dfrac{1}{2m} \lt \dfrac{1}{2m - 1} $$ which I still think is correct. And yes I am convinced the sequence converges by the Monotone Convergence Theorem. The formula for the difference  $x_{n + 1} - x_n$ proves the sequence increases and the bound for $x_n$ is also easy to obtain. But I am unclear as to what I've done wrong. And I am unable to figure it out. Unfortunately I don't understand most of @Sami Ben Romdhane's answer since I have not studied o-notation yet.

Comment: No actually it should be $$ \dfrac{m - n}{4m^2} $$  and this solves my issues. Thanks loads for the response.

Comment: But then you should get $ \frac{m-n}{2m(2m-1)}>\frac{m-n}{4m^2}$, which will not contradict the Cauchy criterion.

Comment: So everything is OK now...

Answer (score 2):

Using this result:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\log n+\gamma+o(1)$$
we see that 
$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\log 2+o(1)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\log 2$$

Comment: You're welcome.